# user presence in online/offline using flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a chatting application using flutter and firebase as backend and the chat function is working fine. But i want to show user presents in online indicator like other chatting app. please help me to implement this feature in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to create a new category in your Firebase database called onlineUsers or something to that affect. Every time a user logs into your app, add them to this newly created category. When a user logs out remove them. Then you can query on that category check if the user you are looking for is logged in or not.

You could also just save a user object for each user that signs up and change the isOnline property of that object to true/false depending when they login/logoff. Then create a firestore rule-set to only let logged in users see this parameter of any specific user object, in which they would query by either username, email or uid.

Answer (score 2):

You should use presence in the realtime database  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence